# Can i create reports and print DataGridView data in c#?

Tags: c#, printing, datagridview, report

I have this code in which the user needs to create Price Offers for clients, the user searches the database for products by entering the name of the product and gets all the matching results in a DataGridView and then he chooses the product he wants to include in the price Offer and adds the amount he wants to calculate the price of and the result goes to another DataGridView which i used to keep the data of all the products needed for the offer, i then need to print the offer out but I couldn't find a way to create a Report from the second DataGridView since it's not connected to a dataSet, is there a way I can do that. here is my code for the whole process which works perfect, i just need to add the reporting part.

```
   //here i created a Function to retrieve data from Sql Table into DataGridView
     private void Display_SPOdata()
          {
              con.Open();
              SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
              cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
              cmd.CommandText = "Select Prod_Name, Date_of_Prod, Date_of_Exp, Unit_Type, Max_Unit_Sell_Price, Min_Unit_Sell_Price, Total_Amount from [Product_Amount] Where Prod_Name = N'"+SellPOproductNameTB.Text+"' and Total_Amount <>'0'";
              cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
              DataTable dt = new DataTable();
              SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
              da.Fill(dt);
              SellPOdatagrid1.DataSource = dt;
              con.Close();

          }
    //here i called the previous function to run when the user presses the search button
          private void button62_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
              Display_SPOdata();
          }

private void SellPOdatagrid1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
          {//here i assigned Varubles to the Keep the entities i need when the cell is clicked  to send to the next dataGradeView
              indexRow = e.RowIndex;


              DataGridViewRow row = SellPOdatagrid1.Rows[indexRow];

              productname = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
              dateofprod = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
              dateofexp = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
              unittype = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
              minsp = row.Cells[5].Value.ToString();

          }    
//here the chosen product goes to the Second DataGridView after entering the Quantity to make the calculations
          private void SellPOaddBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
              int totalPrice = 0;
              int row1 = 0;
              SellPOdataGrid2.Rows.Add();
              row1 = SellPOdataGrid2.Rows.Count - 2;
              SellPOdataGrid2["SPO_ProductName", row1].Value = productname;
              SellPOdataGrid2["SPO_DateOfProduction",row1].Value = dateofprod;
                  SellPOdataGrid2["SPO_DateOfExpiry",row1].Value = dateofexp;
                  SellPOdataGrid2["SPO_UnitType",row1].Value = unittype;
                  SellPOdataGrid2["SPO_Price",row1].Value = minsp;
                  SellPOdataGrid2["SPO_Quantity",row1].Value = SellPOquantityTB.Text;
                  SellPOdataGrid2["SPO_TotalPrice", row1].Value = Convert.ToInt32(SellPOquantityTB.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(minsp);
                  foreach (DataGridViewRow row2 in SellPOdataGrid2.Rows)
                  {
                      totalPrice += Convert.ToInt32(row2.Cells["SPO_TotalPrice"].Value);
                  }
                  SellPOtotalPriceTB.Text = totalPrice.ToString();
          }
```

what i need is to put SPOdataGridView2 Data into a Report.

Comment: Your description of the data organization is nice; the code that does this is also nice, however, what have you tried as far as the “printing” of the data? I am guessing you may want to peruse the [PrintDocument Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) as a possible start.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't do anything regarding printing, because I didn't know how to start since all the answers i found couldn't fit in my code.

Comment: Try something. My comment for the print document class is a good start.

Comment: The `PrintDocument` Class is not difficult. Most problems arise if there are multiple pages. Forget multiple pages at this time and focus on printing ONE page. SO cannot write the code for you without showing some effort. Again… TRY SOMETHING and post what does not work as expected.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it and let you know the results

Answer (score 0):

Here (http://csharp.net-informations.com/datagridview/csharp-datagridview-printing.htm) you will get to know how the printing works in C#. You will get familiarity with print documents in C#. A dynamic approach is mentioned here. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28046/Printing-of-DataGridView